# codeigniter session data lost on ssl

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have session data lost issue on codeigniter. When user logged in, it stores session data but as soon as user goes to another page the session data is lost. What can caused this ? This issue appeared when i switched to site ssl.

Config file:

```
$config['cookie_prefix']    = '';
$config['cookie_domain']    = '';
$config['cookie_path']      = '/';
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
$config['cookie_httponly']  = FALSE;

$config['base_url'] = 'https://blabla.com/';
```

Login proccess

```
public function login_user_process(){
        $params = [
            'user_email' => $this->input->post('user_email'),
            'password' => $this->input->post('user_pass')
        ];
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('user_email', 'E-Posta', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('user_pass', 'Password', 'required');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('status', '0');
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'Username and password field can not be null.');
            redirect('login', 'refresh');
        }

        $check_activation = $this->db->where('user_email', $params['user_email'])->get('aj_users')->row_array();
        if ( $check_activation['activation_code'] != null ){
            $this->session->set_flashdata('status', '0');
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'Please active your account by email we have sent on registration. If you can not reach activation email please click <a href="'.base_url().'resend_activation" class="resendActivation">resend activation code</a>');
            redirect('login', 'refresh');
        }

        $query = $this->index_model->loginCheck($params['user_email'], $params['password']);
        if ( $query != null ){
            $session_data = array(
                'email' => $params['user_email'],
                'user_role' => $query['user_role'],
                'is_logged' => 1,
                'agent' => $_SERVER ['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
                'user_id' => $query['table_id']
            );
            $this->session->set_userdata($session_data);
            if ( $query['user_role'] == 'OPERATOR' ){
                redirect('../operators/profile_edit', 'refresh');
            }
            if ( $query['user_role'] == 'USER' ){
                redirect('../user/my_account', 'refresh');
            }
        }else{
            $this->session->set_flashdata('status', '0');
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'Wrong username and password.');
            redirect('login', 'refresh');
        }
```

it was working on non ssl version. And now its not working.

Comment: Are you directing your users to a non-SSL page?

Comment: Nope, after login process it goes to login check controller and if turns true then user go to profile page. And then if goes to another page data is losing

Comment: This is happening because the URL with SSL and without SSL is two different URLs and codeignitor use to store session in cookies so with SSL and without SSL are two different URL for cookie that's why it log out the user if you try to go without SSL URL you see the user will be logged in there.

Comment: My base url is https://....com and all forms and controllers redirect ssl version. I dont use non ssl url on website

Comment: did you change the $config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE; to TRUE

Comment: Yes i did and it didnt work also

Comment: Please edit your question to include `$config` values for session and cookie settings. Also, a minimal example of the code showing the session data being set and where you expect to find it would be useful.

Comment: I have edited with code examples.

Comment: I am having same situation, @erdinc any luck.